# Generating a random point on a hypersphere that is halfway between two points that are opposite each other

Tags: geometry

I understand how to generate a random point on a hyper-sphere, centered at the origin, when the point could be anywhere on the sphere but what about when the randomly generated point needs to be halfway between two other points that are opposite of each other?

Comment: This is unclear. What do you mean by "opposite"?

Comment: As in a locus of our randomly generated 2 opposite points?

Comment: I’m guessing that by “hypersphere” you mean $S^n$, for instance the set of points at unit distance from the origin in $(n+1)$-space? And by “opposite” I’m guessing that you mean antipodal points on $S^n$? Are these points given to you by telling you their coordinates? Or can you choose any two antipodal points, such as $(\pm1,0,0,\cdots,0)$?

Comment: @Lubin, yes I mean antipode points.  The two points are given by telling you their coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two points on $S^n$ are $(\pm 1,0,0,\cdots,0)$ you just need to choose a random point on $S^{n-1}$ for the last $n-1$ coordinates and prepend a $0$.

If you are given the two points and they are not $(\pm 1,0,0,\cdots,0)$, find the rotation matrix that takes one of them to $(1,0,0,\cdots,0)$.  It will take the other to $(-1,0,0,\cdots,0)$.  Now use the first paragraph, then rotate back by using the inverse of the rotation matrix you got before.